# Converting RAID partitions to LVM

Tags: lvm, raid, fedora

I have a 3TB HDD. of type RAID 5. I want to convert it to LVM. How can I do this without data loss and without needing for installing the OS again?

```
$ df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/mpatha4   96G  3.7G   88G   5% /
devtmpfs             6.9G     0  6.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                6.9G   80K  6.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                6.9G  908K  6.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                6.9G     0  6.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                6.9G  8.1M  6.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/mpatha2  190M   66M  115M  37% /boot
/dev/mapper/mpatha3  289G  2.3G  272G   1% /var
/dev/mapper/mpatha6  2.3T  1.9T  381G  83% /mydata



$ cat /proc/driver/cciss/cciss0
cciss0: HP Smart Array E200i Controller
Board ID: 0x3211103c
Firmware Version: 1.72
IRQ: 65
Logical drives: 1
Current Q depth: 0
Current # commands on controller: 0
Max Q depth since init: 1
Max # commands on controller since init: 165
Max SG entries since init: 31
Sequential access devices: 0


$ fdisk -l
Disk /dev/cciss/c0d0: 3000.5 GB, 3000513552384 bytes, 5860378032 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

           Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1   *           1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/mapper/mpatha: 3000.5 GB, 3000513552384 bytes, 5860378032 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

             Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mapper/mpatha1   *           1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

....
```

Comment: Given it's 3TB give the output of `gdisk -l ...` instead of `fdisk`. `fdisk` can only do MBR and you have to use GPT for anything over 2TB.